# X Theme + Slider Revolution. Extra Space

Tags: wordpress, themes

https://baskingrock.com/homethy/

Hi, I'm using Slider Revolution + X Theme.

I can't seem to understand what's making this extra white space between the slider and the footer.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some extra margin. Just add the style in theme option custom css box .

```
.x-container.offset {
    margin: 0;
}
```